# Facebook php sdk returns user id after logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am using latest facebook php sdk for my app.
I am getting issue with its logout. 
here is my code for logout.

```
<?php
$logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
  'next' => 'https://www.thevoucherlink.com/logout.php'));
?>
```

And this is my logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['fb_uid']);
session_destroy();
header('location:https://www.thevoucherlink.com/index.php?ref=logout');
?>
```

After log out user log outs from facebook. But not from my app.

`$user_id=$facebook->getUser();`

This function returns the user id after log out.

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It log outs when i logout two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing FB cookie along with unsetting session, like:

```
session_start();
$fb_key = 'fbs_'."YOUR_FB_APP_ID";
setcookie($fb_key, '', time() - 3600, '', '/', '');
unset($_SESSION['fb_uid']);
session_destroy();
```

Then you can try doing try..catch block, something like:

```
$userId = $facebook->getUser();
try {
   $myDetails = $facebook->api('/me');
   //will return details if still loggedin
} catch (Exception $e) {
   //user has already logged out
}
```

### Edited

In your logout.php, try doing:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'your_id', 'secret' => 'your_secret'));
//destroy the session
$facebook->destroySession();
```

Comment: I tried this code but Its not working. If i refreshed logout.php two times than it logouts. But not with single press.

Comment: try {
   $myDetails = $facebook->api('/me');
  print_r($myDetails);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'loged out';exit;
}
//still not working :(

Comment: does the print_r($myDetails); show details actually...! after you logged out...?

Comment: Yes thats the problem. Its returning all user details after logout too.

Comment: Thank you bro so much. It worked $facebook->destroySession(); this function did it. like on proshore days.. haha

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16590/discussion-between-krishna-karki-and-sudhir)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `offline_access` from `scope`-parameter of login URL of Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

May be the log-out link is logging out the user from Facebook, not from your application.

You have to use `$this->Auth->logout();` to logout the user from your application.

OR

Try to use integration of PHP SDK with Javascript SDK.